# How to wrap lines automatically in Python Spyder?

Tags: python, spyder, pep8

I'm new to Python.
I'm using Spyder 4.0.1, Python 3.7.
The Spyder built-in PEP-8 convention code style check returns error E501 (line too long). Although I set the vertical line and wrap lines, it still shows error for the long characters line. Pycharm would wrap lines automatically, but I cannot find any effective solution in Spyder.
What should I do? Do I have to press Enter manually for the long line? Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

In Windows Go To
Tools->Preferences->Editor and select Wrap lines.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

If you use mac, you need to go to **Python** on the left right corner then click on **Preferences**.
[image]

---

Then go to **Editor**, and check **Wrap lines**.
[image]

Comment: Works on Windows 10 also.

Answer (score 0):

To turn on the Word Wrap feature, go to View > Toggle Word Wrap or click the Edit Display icon in the Code Editor toolbar (it's the second-to-last one on the right) and select Toggle Word Wrap. You can also set the program preferences to keep this feature on by default.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not able to find this Toggle Word Wrap in my Python3.7.

Comment: You have to go to **Tools** > **Preferences**, then in the Preferences window go to **Editor**. In the Display tab check **Wrap lines**.